# Jenkins Google Play Android Publisher plugin androidApkMove not moving Release Notes between Tracks

Tags: android, jenkins, google-play, apk

I've just finished adding and implementing the Google Play Android Publisher plugin for Jenkins for both uploading APKs and moving them between tracks in the Google Play Console.

I'm using Version 1.8 of the plugin.

https://github.com/jenkinsci/google-play-android-publisher-plugin
https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/google-play-android-publisher/#androidapkmove-move-android-apks-to-a-different-release-track

The Uploading is working flawlessly and is even putting my Release Notes for the specified languages into Google Play correctly, by using this:

```
def getDeployNotes() {
    return [language: 'en-US', text: "${env.DEPLOY_NOTES}"]
}

androidApkUpload googleCredentialsId        : signingCredential,
                 apkFilesPattern            : "app/build/outputs/apk/${variant.flavor}/${variant.type}/*.apk",
                 deobfuscationFilesPattern  : "app/build/outputs/mapping/${variant.flavor}/${variant.type}/mapping.txt",
                 trackName                  : 'alpha',
                 recentChangeList           : [getDeployNotes()]
```

It produces this result in the Alpha Track in the Play Console (Note the "Here are some deploy notes, let's see if they persist during APK Move.")

[image]

Now, to Move the APK between Tracks in the Play Console, I use "androidApkMove" like so

```
androidApkMove applicationId        : release.packageName,
               fromVersionCode      : true,
               googleCredentialsId  : release.googleCredentialsId,
               rolloutPercentage    : env.ROLLOUT_PERCENTAGE,
               trackName            : env.TO_TRACK,
               versionCodes         : env.VERSION_NUMBER
```

Which produces this result in the Beta Track in the Play Console (Note there are no release notes)

[image]

I'm at a loss as to what to do here and I've read through the documentation for the plugin, but I've yet to find anything.  Has anybody else encountered this issue and if so, know a solution to it?  Doing this all manually for 78 Flavors is not favorable.

Answer (score 1):

Copying over the release notes from one track to another isn't done automatically by Google Play when promoting existing files to another release track via the API (unlike when you do it from the web UI).

However, since [version 4.0](https://github.com/jenkinsci/google-play-android-publisher-plugin/releases/tag/google-play-android-publisher-4.0) of the Google Play Android Publisher Plugin, this functionality is built in: moving app versions between tracks will also copy over the release notes.